# Show that there is no periodic orbit for the system $x'=-y+x^2-xy, y'=x+xy$ by Dulac criterion.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $h(x,y)=(1+y)^{-3}(-1-x)^{-1}, f(x,y)=-y+x^2-xy$ and $g(x,y)=x+xy$.
Then,
$$\frac{\partial(fh)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial(gh)}{\partial y}=\frac{x^2}{(1+x)^2(1+y)^3}.$$
My question is $\frac{\partial(fh)}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial(gh)}{\partial y}$ has same sign when $y \leq -1$ and $y \geq -1$.
This means there is no periodic orbit in the region $\{(x,y):y \leq -1\}$ and $\{(x,y):y \geq -1\}$. But not on the whole plane.
Am I right?
And how to prove that there is no periodic orbit on $\mathbb{R}^2$?
Thank you!